# VBA WEB scraping loop

Tags: vba, internet-explorer, web-scraping

This is the code I wrote I need it to loop when it copy and paste the table and then click the next button till there no more next button , the next button is a tagname "a" and it has a "href" that I used to click the hyper link
Any help would be appreciated thanks

```
Sub GetData()
    'define variables
    Dim i As SHDocVw.InternetExplorer

    Set i = New InternetExplorer

    i.Visible = True

    Dim IE As Object, obj As Object
    Dim r As Long, c As Long, t As Long
    Dim elemCollection As Object
    Dim eRow As Long
    Dim HTMLDoc As MSHTML.HTMLDocument
    Dim HTMLInput As MSHTML.IHTMLElement
    Dim HTMLAs As MSHTML.IHTMLElementCollection
    Dim HTMLA As MSHTML.IHTMLElement

    url_name = Sheet2.Range("e4")

    If url_name = "" Then Exit Sub

    i.Visible = True
    i.navigate (url_name)

    Do While i.readyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE
    Loop

    'we ensure that the web page is downloaded completely
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("a2:ai1000").ClearContents

    Set elemCollection = i.document.getElementsByTagName("TABLE")

    For t = 0 To (elemCollection.Length - 1)

        For r = 0 To (elemCollection(t).Rows.Length - 1)

            eRow = Sheet1.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row

            For c = 0 To (elemCollection(t).Rows(r).Cells.Length - 1)

                ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Cells(eRow, c + 1) = elemCollection(t).Rows(r).Cells(c).innerText

            Next c

        Next r

    Next t

    Range("a1:ai1000").Columns.AutoFit

    'Clean up Memory

    Set IE = Nothing

    Set HTMLDoc = i.document

    Set HTMLAs = HTMLDoc.getElementsByTagName("a")

    For Each HTMLA In HTMLAs

        'Debug.Print HTMLA.getAttribute("classname"), HTMLA.getAttribute("href")

        If HTMLA.getAttribute("classname") = "button2 next" And HTMLA.getAttribute("href") = "https://stathead.com/football/pgl_finder.cgi?request=1&game_num_max=99&week_num_max=99&order_by=all_td&match=game&season_start=1&year_max=2020&qb_gwd=0&qb_comeback=0&season_end=-1&game_type=R&age_max=99&year_min=2020&offset=100" Then

            HTMLA.Click

            Exit For

        End If

    Next
    
End Sub
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! To avoid frustration please read this blog post about how to get good answers: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @HackSlash: That's not a blog post. It's a help center page.

Comment: Add a loop while i.document.querySelectorAll(".next").Length > 0, adding in the appropriate page load wait and other code inside the loop - maybe calling a helper sub which writes out the current table, and a helper function to determine the appropriate write to start writing out from.

Comment: I agree with QHarr's suggestion. You can try to add your code in the loop he describes. You can show us what you have tried and tell us if there're some issues. If you need further help, please also provide the html code or the website link so that we can have a better understading of the issue.